# Angular 2 [style.margin-top]

Tags: angular

I need to get height of img and then change `margin-top` subtract from it height of img. 
I tried this code below but unfortunately this didn't work

```
<img [style.marginTop.px]="marginTop - '[style.height.px]' "class="noteImg">
```

How elegant resolve this question ? 
I will be glad any your suggestions.

Full code

```
<div class="container-fluid noteContainer" *ngFor="let data of dataPost; let i = index">
    <div class="noteWrapperImg">
        <img [style.marginTop.px]="HOW TO DO IT?" src="{{data?.image}}" class="noteImg" alt="{{data?.altImage}}">
        <a class="{{i%2 == 1 ? 'notePDataNotEven': 'notePDataEven'}}" [class.css]="i%2 == 1">
           <i class="ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> {{data?.data}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My suggestion is using `load` event on image https://plnkr.co/edit/4GWddzmcOeSgmvtAdlRM?p=preview

Comment: that's interesting solve! thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The proper node's style margin-top property is `marginTop`, but you cannot do it like this. You should access style in your component and retrieve height property first yo use it in your template.

As you use an `*ngFor` loop, you can do it by adding a template variable to image and passing it to some method that returns its height. Like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataPost>
    <img #img [style.marginTop.px]="getImgMarginTop(img)" src="http://image-src.png">
</div>
```

Then add to your component a method that returns your image height.

```
  getImgMarginTop(img) {
    return img.style.marginTop - img.clientHeight
  }
```

Comment: Didn't notice that you try too subtract '[style.height.px]' late at night sorry) Yeah, @Michael is right - you cannot do it like this. You should access it from your component fist.

Comment: that seems to work. But i have a final question. If i run this code with console.log() 
 `getImgMarginTop(img) {
      console.log(img.clientHeight);
  }`
then console shows a kind of haos. Why this method called so many times?
http://i056.radikal.ru/1611/ba/73fb22aa6f2a.png

Comment: You mean nultiple logs? That's normal - angular change detection works that way

Comment: I think i understand that thank you for your time. And Can you fix your a small mistake? getImgMarginTop(img) instead getImgMargin(img).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot get value from using directive `[style.height.px]`, your best option is using direct access to the DOM using [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) and then access its [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) property, and used it in your calculation

Comment: i don't use that because img is in cycle "for of". If I have to do so then the code will have two cycle.